# How to update an SVN branch made with svn-copy?

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

noob question I know, but all resources I found fail or gave me the new problem.

I have few branches in my SVN repo. All developers get access to his personal branch. Each branch was made by a copy from the beta branch.

```
svn copy  svn://192.168.0.2/svn/example/branches/beta
svn://192.168.0.2/svn/example/branches/dev/devN
```

Now when dev1 finished to work, he merge his work in beta (pwd = ./beta/)

```
svn merge svn://192.168.0.2/svn/example/branches/dev/dev1@4242 .
```

Well, my question is, how other dev could update her own branch to the latest beta with dev1 change?

when dev2 do a merge (after commited his own change | pwd = ./dev/dev2)

```
svn merge svn://192.168.0.2/svn/example/branches/beta@4242 .
```

He get this message:

```
svn: E195016: Merge tracking not allowed with missing subtrees; try restoring these items first:
pointing his files. -> impossible to merge.
```

Is there a way to "update" a branch copy?

Comment: BTW, common merge pattern avoid using PEG-revisions in source

Comment: This is not the proper approach. Instead of creating separate branch for each users, you should create one branch and users should checkout from this branch and they should work in their workspace and commit their changes. So other users get the changes just by updating their working copy. This should make your life easier.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That error message occurs when someone deletes something without telling Subversion about it.  If you were to run `svn status` on that working copy the same path that Subversion is complaining about should show with a `!` in the first column of the output.  Usually this means that someone used an OS command to delete paths rather than a svn command.

If you really want the paths to be deleted then you can fix this by telling Subversion about this by doing using the `svn rm` command.  The paths will show as deleted with a `D` in the first column of status output and your merge should proceed (though you might have tree conflicts).

If you want the gory details see [issue #2915](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=2915) from the Subversion project that explains why this error message was added.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working in windows and the path exceeds 256 characters, Windows will start being nasty about things.  I usually get around this by creating the workspace directly under a short directory in root file system (e.g. C:\WRK)  This will use a path much shorter than C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\ directory.  Once I have my workspace created, I add a shortcut to my desktop for easy access.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting this error and I just did a checkout with TortoiseSVN.  Nothing has been deleted.
I did find that at the end of a long path, there was a "common" directory created which doesn't appear when I go to the Repo-broswer.  If I delete the parent directory and do an update, the "common" directory appears again.  The parent directory also shows a red X which indicates TortoiseSVN thinks something has been deleted via an OS command, rather than with an SVN delete command.

I think there is a bug somewhere in the code.  I don't know if it has to do with the path length (an issue for Windows 7?) or if there is some other issue going on.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred to me on a Windows client when there was a file in the repository with a mixed case name and another file with a uppercase name in windows. E.g. "Test.xml" in the repository and "TEST.XML" in the repository.
So Subversion seems to be case sensitive here and Windows case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same message. svn status said that one file had a !. It was in my filesystem, svn had it in its database but svn also thought it was deleted (which it wasn't). I had to remove it, delete it via subversion, commit everything until svn status was okay and the file was really missing. After that I copied the mysterious file back to place, added it and committed it again. After that subversion and filesystem were back synced. This must have been an error in subversion. But luckily I could fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same symptom, with a fresh checkout, using the cygwin subversion client, version 1.13.0, on Windows.  I don't know if it was the path length or a case problem, as other answers suggest, but switching to linux host and doing a fresh checkout with a client version 1.7.14, solved my problem.